# How do I make this IAM role error in aws sagemaker go away?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I suspect this has to more to do with IAM roles than Sagemaker.

I'm following the example [here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/README.rst)

Specifically, when it makes this call

```
tf_estimator.fit('s3://bucket/path/to/training/data')
```

I get this error

```
ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::013772784144:assumed-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20181022T195630/SageMaker is not authorized to perform: iam:GetRole on resource: role SageMakerRole
```

My notebook instance has an IAM role attached to it.
That role has the `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess` policy. It also has a custom policy that looks like this

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

My input files and .py script is in an s3 bucket with the phrase `sagemaker` in it.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're running the example code on a SageMaker notebook instance, you can use the execution_role which has the `AmazonSageMakerFullAccess` attached.

```
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
role = get_execution_role()
```

And you can pass this role when initializing `tf_estimator`.
You can check out the example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/automatic-model-tuning-ex-role.html) for using `execution_role` with S3 on notebook instance.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

This is not an issue with S3 Bucket policy but for IAM, The user role that you're choosing has a policy attached that **doesn't give it permissions to manage other IAM roles**. You'll need to make sure the role you're using can manage (create, read, update) IAM roles.

Hope this helps !

Comment: yes, you were onto something. I just didn't know what to do about that until @Han pointed it out

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: This is the answer, inside role that is automictically created by SageMaker when we create user in SM dashboard (e.g. AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx). Add the new permission called IAMFullAccess. That work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `aws configure` and make sure you are the expected user. If not, change / update your credentials.This worked for me.